# Export shapefile From PostGIS

Tags: postgis, convert, ogr2ogr, fwtools, pgsql2shp

I've a website where I'm giving the functionality of creating and editing line features. I'm using [Leaflet-Draw](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw) plugin for drawing, `PostGIS` for storing the data and `GeoJSON` to display it on map.

My next task is to add the **Export** functionality. I've search around and found that using `ogr2ogr` I can convert a `PostGIS` table to shapefile. But this query works in `FWTools`, how can I run it on server. Another way I found is to use `pgsql2shp`. But I don't know where to run this command. I run this in Postgres `console` and `SQL Editor` but getting error.

The thing is I want to know

What is the best way in my case to export data to shapefile and how to perform it?

Comment: Just install GDAL and run it from terminal

Answer (score 5):

Just install [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/) and run it from Bash / terminal.

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" mydata.shp PG:"host=myhost user=myloginname dbname=mydbname password=mypassword" "mytable"
```

Or do not even bother with GDAL and just use something like below in terminal.

```
# pgsql2shp -f myfile -p 5555 my_db roads_table
```

Comment: Ok, with luck, I'm able to run secund query. But this is creating a Shapefile locally on my system. How to run this query on server?

Comment: This part is not really GIS specific but far more about your server structure. The simple answer is run the query on the server.